# How to define rails constant Mailer::ApplicationMailer for Heroku deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, actionmailer

I have a rails application that is crashing because the `ActionMailer` constant apparently doesn't exist or something but it does. 
Here are my Heroku logs:

```
2020-06-02T14:54:19.581698+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=beulah-ror-portfolio-1.herokuapp.com request_id=730c40fd-29b8-45f6-ac94-98839a66611a fwd="105.112.46.202" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2020-06-02T14:54:21.801858+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=beulah-ror-portfolio-1.herokuapp.com request_id=fe307ff5-6d4f-4305-a74d-54afeb92e3d6 fwd="105.112.46.202" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2020-06-02T14:54:35.626782+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=beulah-ror-portfolio-1.herokuapp.com request_id=ef7cd106-36d2-4a6e-93e3-aea874aa2c4d fwd="102.67.23.174" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2020-06-02T14:54:36.594530+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=beulah-ror-portfolio-1.herokuapp.com request_id=e6a8e65b-8aba-4165-aad8-890a2f505e82 fwd="102.67.23.174" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2020-06-02T14:56:05.955005+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rails c` by user akibeulah@gmail.com
2020-06-02T14:56:20.095915+00:00 heroku[run.6268]: State changed from starting to up
2020-06-02T14:56:20.269238+00:00 heroku[run.6268]: Awaiting client
2020-06-02T14:56:20.298273+00:00 heroku[run.6268]: Starting process with command `rails c`
2020-06-02T14:56:30.227209+00:00 heroku[run.6268]: Process exited with status 1
2020-06-02T14:56:30.288477+00:00 heroku[run.6268]: State changed from up to complete
```

Here is the output from the console:

```
1: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:17:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader/callbacks.rb:17:in `on_file_autoloaded': expected file /app/app/models/mailers/application_mailer.rb to define constant Mailers::ApplicationMailer, but didn't (Zeitwerk::NameError)
```

So my thinking was the Application mailer was not generated properly, so I regenerated it. It still did not work. I am thinking of removing the mailer entirely as I am not really using it at the moment. However, I want to know in case the error repeats itself in another project.

Here is my application mailer:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'from@example.com'
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

At this point, I believe there is something I do not understand. What could cause this error besides the application_mailer.rb?

I have tried restarting the Heroku app and also migrating the db... still nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap `ApplicationMailer` inside the `Mailers` namespace - module.

```
module Mailers
  class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: 'from@example.com'
    layout 'mailer'
  end
end
```

That's at least basically what the error message "/mailers/application_mailer.rb to define constant Mailers::ApplicationMailer" is trying to tell you.

However, I am a bit confused that your `mailers` directory is nested inside `app/models` - I would expect it to be in `app/mailers`

So maybe better try to move the `mailers` directory out of the `models` and try without wrapping it in the module.

Comment: Oh my gosh... I must have accidentally moved it while trying to click open files in the neighbouring folders, that was the issue. I just deleted it from models, cause there was already an `app/mailers` folder. Thank you for drawing my attention to that.